# How can I have Python read variables from a browser?

Tags: javascript, python, browser

On a school project, I am trying to code an AI to a simple game.
The problem is that the game is a javascript code running in a browser, while the AI is to be coded with Python.

I have isolated the useful real-time variables (like position, speed...) in the .js file, and I was able to output them in the browser debug console.

How could I have Python access those variables, in real time?

Edit: To make myself more clear, I am trying to beat Chromium's T-Rex Runner. Here is my modified version, showing useful informations in the console: https://github.com/17maxd/t-rex-runner/ .

Comment: Please start with posting some code of where you currently stand and we can help you out with that. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you only code the javascript or did you also code a server in Python as well?

Comment: Will the AI play the game by observing the game state and interacting with the Web UI? Or will the AI be the opponent in the game?

Comment: the game is chromium's T-Rex, of which I run a local copy so I can edit the code. I want to run a local python script aside to interact with it.

Comment: I have no trouble in making Python "playing" the game, as I just need to fake pressing up and down arrows. My problem is in letting Python knowing what happens.

Comment: are you using selenium to make python "play" the game or something else?

Comment: I will just emulate up and down keys from python, so nope. It's a very simplistic game.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come through my mind:

1. The game's server code may expose API (e.g. REST API) via which your AI could query parameters and execute commands.
2. Make your AI interact with game just like human would using [selenium-python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Using Selenium you can read state at any time by executing JS in browser like this (assuming your page includes jQuery):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://example.com')

some_value = driver.execute_script('return $("#some_id").val();')

driver.close()
```